# rpy2, copula, How to import parameters? Python

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2, code-translation

I would like to translate:

```
    library(copula)
myCop.clayton <- archmCopula(family="clayton", dim =7, param=2)
myMvd <- mvdc(copula=myCop.clayton, margins=c("norm", "norm"),
              paramMargins = list(list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1),
                              list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1)))
```

into Python using rpy2

```
`myMvd = copula.mvdc(copula=myCop, margins=robjects.StrVector(["norm", "norm"]),
              paramMargins = robjects.vectors.ListVector(
                  [robjects.vectors.FloatVector([0.66, 0.1]), 
                   robjects.vectors.FloatVector([0.66, 0.1])]))`
```

But unfortunately plots generated in RStudio and Python interpreter are quite different. How can I translate:

```
paramMargins = list(list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1), list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1))
```

into Python?

Best regards
Rafal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R code
    library(copula)
    myCop_clayton <- archmCopula(family="clayton", dim =7, param=2)
    myMvd <- mvdc(copula=myCop_clayton, margins=c("norm", "norm"),
                  paramMargins = list(list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1),
                                      list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1)))

can be translated to rpy2 simply, by using snippets of R codes where the translation appears complicated to you. For example:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
copula = importr('copula')
myCop_clayton = copula.archmCopula(family="clayton", dim =7, param=2)
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector, ListVector
from rpy2.robjects import r
myMvd = copula.mvdc(copula=myCop,
                    margins=StrVector(["norm", "norm"]),
                    paramMargins = r("""
                                     list(list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1),
                                          list(mean=0.66,sd = 0.1))
                                     """))
```

Otherwise `paramMargins` can be expressed as:

```
ListVector([("V1", ListVector([{"mean": 0.66, "sd": 0.1}])), 
            ("V2", ListVector([{"mean": 0.66, "sd": 0.1}]))])
```